# Creating test that depends on another test case

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

I'm currently working on an application that uploads a file to a web service (using spring resttemplate). This upload function returns an id which can be used to download the uploaded file later on.

I want this scenario covered by a test (i'm not talking about unit test - maybe integration or functional test, whichever is appropriate).

What i want to do is the download test case will depends on the result of the upload test (since the id will comes from the upload function) - this will be tested against an actual web service for me to confirm if the upload and download functions works properly.

I'm not sure if this approach that i want to do is correct so if any one can suggest a good approach how to implement it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since this upload/download functionality is already covered on Unit level

> I want this scenario covered by a test (i'm not talking about unit test - maybe integration or functional test, whichever is appropriate).

I know [Test chaining](http://xunitpatterns.com/Chained%20Tests.html) is considered harmful

> the download test case will depends on the result of the upload test (since the id will comes from the upload function)

and can cause lots of overlap between tests, so changes to one can cascade outwards and cause failures everywhere. Further more the tests should have Atomicity (isolation). But if the trade-off in your case suite you, my advice is to use it.

What you can look at, is a proper [Test Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/test%20fixture%20-%20xUnit.html) strategy. The other [Fixture Setup](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html) patterns can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an 'acceptance test' is what is required. This would be basically an integration test of a subsystem for the desired feature. 
Have a look at [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io) as a good easy framework to get started.

Here you would define your steps
Given:
When:
Then:

and you can then test the feature as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Services external (that You have no control over) to Your application has to be mocked, even in e2e test.

This means that service where You are uploading file should be faked. Just setup dummy http server that is pretending to be real service.

With such fake service you can setup it's behaviour for every test, in example you can prepare file to be downloaded with given id.

Pseudo code:

```
// given
file = File(id, content);
fakeFileService.addFile(file);

// when
applicationRunner.downloadFile(file.id());

// then
assertThatFileWasDownloaded(file);
```

This is a test which checks if application can download given file.

- `File` class is some domain object in Your application, not a system
  File!
- `fakeFileService` is instance that controls dummy file service.
- `applicationRunner` is a wrapper around Your application that makes
  it do what you want.

**I recommend You to read "Growing Object-Oriented software guided by tests".**